# MATLAB curve fitting for an arbitrary data set

Tags: matlab, accelerometer, curve-fitting

I have a data set from an accelerometer sensor. it provides the acceleration value in each 20ms. 
Now I want to fit a curve to this data set then use Integral to get the speed of the object.

I want to use MATLAB curve fitting, however I don't know what fittype I should use. Is MATLAB able to fit curve for any arbitrary data set or I should isolate data set to different sets and fit curve for each one?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Since you don't know the kind of curve that best fit your data it's resonable to expect that you'll have to try many. I suggest that you have a look at the Curve Fitting App, by calling `cftool`. To my knowledge this is the fastest way of proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know what function to use, you could try describing your curve with splines (smoothing splines, such as `csaps` could be useful).

However, it may be much easier to numerically integrate the data using e.g. [CUMTRAPZ](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html).